# Composer autoload in own package / class not found

Tags: composer-php, classnotfoundexception, autoload

I've tried now some different approaches and read articles here and elsewhere but i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.
I'm developing a package and I want it to be installed via symlink in a different project to develop both parts simultaneously without the need of updating the dependencies over and over again.
The thing I cant get to work is the autoloading.

Here is my setup:

**Project composer.json**

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../../FormTableComponent",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    [...]
    "bluechord/formtablecomponent": "@dev"
  }
}
```

**FormtableComponent Folder Structure**

```
FormTableComponent/
  src/
  | Container.php
  composer.json
```

**FormtableComponent composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "bluechord/formtablecomponent",
  "description": "...",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "BlueChord\\FormTableComponent\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "require" : {
    [...]
  }
}
```

**FormtableComponent Container.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * FormTable Container. The Container Class that registers all Parts of the 
 * Component.
 */

 namespace BlueChord\FormTableComponent;

 class Container {

    function __construct() {

    }
 }
```

When I try to use the class and instantiate it I get

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'BlueChord\FormTableComponent\Container' not found
```

Thanks for your help!

ADDITIONAL INFO:

**A simple Test.php which reproduces the error inside the project**

```
<?php

require_once 'bin/vendor/autoload.php';
echo "BCOSP Test";

use DebugBar\StandardDebugBar;
use BlueChord\FormTableComponent\Container;

$debugbar = new StandardDebugBar(); --> WORKS
echo StandardDebugBar::class ."\n";

$container = new Container();  --> ERROR
echo Container::class . "\n";
```

**Composer**

The vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php does NOT contain any array key for my package.

If I run `composer dump-autoload` inside my main project nothing changes.
If I run `composer dump-autoload` inside my package it creates the correct autoload_psr4.php

Comment: Please share more details: how does that script to "use the class" look like? Does it use the autoloader properly? Does the autoloader contain all information for that package?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated with the requested info